# Android sync adapter syncs frequently on small intervals

Tags: android

In my application, I want to make sure that auto sync should be enabled once my application is installed and user has logged in. I am using the following code for this purpose:

```
am = AccountManager.get(MainActivity.this);
account = am.getAccountsByType(AccountGeneral.ACCOUNT_TYPE)[0];

if(!ContentResolver.isSyncActive(account, CloudKiboDatabaseContract.AUTHORITY)) {

    ContentResolver.setSyncAutomatically(account, CloudKiboDatabaseContract.AUTHORITY, true);
    ContentResolver.requestSync(account, CloudKiboDatabaseContract.AUTHORITY, new Bundle());

}
```

This code works on the application start. If the sync is not active, it sets it to start automatically.

However, I checked on my server that it is syncing to server on very small intervals. How can I give it a bigger time interval? or give it a schedule?

It seems to me that `ContentResolver.requestSync()` causes the sync to happen on very small interval.

Kindly, let me know if there is a good solution which also follows the best practices.

**More Information**: I am using sync adapter and account manager in my application.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the last line `ContentResolver.requestSync(account, CloudKiboDatabaseContract.AUTHORITY, new Bundle());`

It prevents auto-sync function, that you set above, and start sync manually and immediately. The auto-sync setting synchronize your data when there are available internet connection, so you don't need check that.

You can read more about correct using of SyncAdapter here - 
https://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/running-sync-adapter.html

Comment: It does not prevent syncing on very short intervals. However, it works whether the last line is removed or not. I have removed the last line. I would look into the link provided too.

Comment: If your main problem, is that even auto-sync called very frequently, you can set [interval manually](https://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/running-sync-adapter.html#RunPeriodic), **instead** of auto-sync (cause setting interval doesn't resets auto-sync).
`ContentResolver.addPeriodicSync(
                ACCOUNT,
                AUTHORITY,
                Bundle.EMPTY,
                SYNC_INTERVAL);`

Comment: Yes, I saw this method on the link you provided. This one does not set the a-sync as true in the settings. User has to go to settings in order to set the sync as true